# Meaning of "... die deutschen Schweden-Freunde mit ihren Elch-Aufklebern an den Autos ..."

Tags: meaning

From the Frankfurter Allgemeine:

> **Selbst wenn es die deutschen Schweden-Freunde mit ihren Elch-Aufklebern an den Autos kaum glauben mögen**: Als Elch hat man es auch in Schweden nicht immer leicht. Da die Tiere in ihrer Vielzahl für Wald und Verkehr eine Gefahr sind - oder einfach nur, weil es Spaß macht -, werden sie gejagt und zu Tausenden getötet.

What does the part in bold mean? As it is typed, "deutschen" with small "d" is an adjective modifying "Schweden-Freunde"? And does "Elch-Aufkleben an den Autos" mean "elk stickers on the cars"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you're right. I would translate it as follows:

> Even though the German friends of Sweden with their elk stickers on the cars hardly believe it:

Comment: Thanks. What does "the german friends of sweden" mean?

Comment: People from germany who like sweden